# Yet Another Proof of Inequality by Induction

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, induction

I need to show by induction that for $ n \geq 1$, the following inequality holds:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \geq\frac{1}{2(n+1) \sqrt{n}}$$

My initial approach would be to use $P(n-1)$ :

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \geq\frac{1}{2(n) \sqrt{n-1}}$$

and then try to show that $P(n-1) \rightarrow P(n)$. Clearly the base case $P(1)$ holds.

I understand that this should be solved by transforming the terms, e.g. by multiplying  the expression $P(n-1)$ by something like $\sqrt(n-1)$... but after a few "guesses" I'm not making any progress. Any hints on how to transform the expression in order to be able to use the inductive step ? Generally, what is a good routine/rule of thumb for tackling these problems ? Do you just start trying out things to modify the expression ?

Comment: *Note: I see how to show that the inequality holds by simply multiplying $P(n)$ by $\sqrt(n)$, but it's the inductive proof part that I'm stuck on.

Comment: Is the inequality $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+1} \geq \frac{1}{2(n+1)\sqrt{n}}$$ as you have originally written or $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \geq \frac{1}{2(n+1)\sqrt{n}}$$ as you have seemingly implied when you find $P(n-1)$?

Comment: I just corrected it, the second term is  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base case $n = 1$ reads: $\dfrac{1}{1} - \dfrac{1}{2} \ge \dfrac{1}{4}$ which is clearly true. Assume the inequality is true for $n = k$, we need to show it is also true for $n = k+1$. This means to prove: $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+1}\ge \dfrac{1}{2(k+2)\sqrt{k+1}}$. We have: $LHS = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+1} \left(\sqrt{k+1}+1\right)}\ge RHS $ because $2(k+2) \ge 1+\sqrt{k+1}$ is quite clear as $2(k+2) = 1+2k+3 \ge 1+k+1 \ge 1 +\sqrt{k+1}$. Thus you are done.

**Note:** This note should come before the two comments below. But it seems that the induction step was not helpful or not necessary in showing the step for $n = k+1$ and this is why I did not invest time in finding ways to link this inductive step to the final step when $n = k+1$.

Comment: Note that this is not in fact a proof by induction: it is a direct proof of the general case of the inequality.

Comment: Right, I realize that. I guess my general question is then: In such cases, do we even need a proof by induction ? Does it not suffice to show the direct proof of the general case for the inequality?

Comment: @JKM: No, there’s absolutely no need for a proof by induction when you can prove the result for all cases simultaneously at least as easily (and in this case a lot more easily).